# Python code to minify JS and CSS on the fly

Tags: javascript, python, performance, css

Below is the python code to compress js and css files.

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import shutil
import fnmatch
import os.path
import re
import argparse
import time

#Store the time the script starts
start_time = time.time()
total_files_compressed = 0
total_js_files_compressed = 0
total_css_files_compressed = 0

jsMinPath = 'min/js'
jsDevPath = 'js'
cssDevPath = 'css'
cssMinPath = 'min/css'
yuicompressorPath = 'yuicompressor.jar'

enable_log = False
retval = os.getcwd()

total_warnings = 0
total_errors = 0

print ("Minification script started") 

def logErrorWarning(filepath):
        global total_warnings
        global total_errors
        logf = open(filepath)
        warning_count = 0
        error_count = 0
        for line in logf:
                if "[ERROR]" in line:
                        error_count = error_count + 1
                        total_errors = total_errors + 1
                if "[WARNING]" in line:
                        warning_count = warning_count + 1
                        total_warnings = total_warnings + 1
        logf.close()
        logOutput("Errors " + str(error_count) + " Total Warnings " + str(warning_count))

def logOutput(text):
        print (text)

def incrementCompressedFileCount():
        global total_files_compressed
        total_files_compressed = total_files_compressed + 1

def incrementCompressedJSFileCount():
        global total_js_files_compressed
        total_js_files_compressed = total_js_files_compressed + 1

def incrementCompressedCSSFileCount():
        global total_css_files_compressed
        total_css_files_compressed = total_css_files_compressed + 1

def minifyJs():

        if not os.path.exists(jsMinPath + "/log"):
                os.makedirs(jsMinPath + "/log")
        else:
                shutil.rmtree(jsMinPath + "/log")
                os.makedirs(jsMinPath + "/log")

        logfile = open(jsMinPath + "/log/fulllog.txt", 'w')

        logfile.write('Minify script started for internal js files\n')


        os.chdir(jsMinPath)
        jsmincontents = glob.glob("*.js")
        logfile.write("Removing existing minified files..\n")
        logfile.write("Total "+ str(len(jsmincontents)) + " min files exist\n")
        for j in jsmincontents:
                os.remove(j)
                logfile.write("Removed file " + j + "..\n")
        os.chdir(retval)
        os.chdir(jsMinPath)
        jsmincontents = glob.glob("*.js")
        os.chdir(retval)

        jscontents = os.listdir(jsDevPath)

        logfile.write("Compressing internal js files ")
        logOutput("Compressing internal js files ")

        for i in jscontents:
                if i.lower().endswith('.js'):
                        command = "java -jar " + yuicompressorPath + " -v " + jsDevPath + "/" + i + " -o " + jsMinPath + "/" + i[0:-3] + ".min.js 2> " + jsMinPath + "/log/" + i[0:-3] + ".log.txt"
                        #print command
                        logfile.write("Compressing file "+ i + "\n")
                        logOutput("Compressing file "+ i + "..")
                        logfile.write(command + "..\n\n")
                        os.system(command)
                        incrementCompressedFileCount()
                        incrementCompressedJSFileCount()
                        logErrorWarning(jsMinPath + "/log/" + i[0:-3] + ".log.txt")

        logfile.close()
        logOutput("All internal js files minified")


def minifyCss():
        if not os.path.exists(cssMinPath + "/log"):
                os.makedirs(cssMinPath + "/log")
        else:
                shutil.rmtree(cssMinPath + "/log")
                os.makedirs(cssMinPath + "/log")

        logfile = open(cssMinPath + "/log/fulllog.txt", 'w')
        logfile.write('Minify script started\n')

        os.chdir(cssMinPath)
        cssmincontents = glob.glob("*.css")
        logfile.write("Removing existing minified files..\n")
        logfile.write("Total "+ str(len(cssmincontents)) + " min files exist\n")
        for j in cssmincontents:
                os.remove(j)
                logfile.write("Removed file " + j + "..\n")
        os.chdir(retval)
        os.chdir(cssMinPath)
        cssmincontents = glob.glob("*.css")
        os.chdir(retval)

        csscontents = os.listdir(cssDevPath)

        logfile.write("Compressing files ")

        for i in csscontents:
                if i.lower().endswith('.css'):
                        command = "java -jar " + yuicompressorPath + " -v " + cssDevPath + "/" + i + " -o " + cssMinPath + "/" + i[0:-4] + ".min.css 2> " + cssMinPath + "/log/" + i[0:-4] + ".log.txt"
                        #print command
                        logfile.write("Compressing file "+ i + "\n")
                        logOutput("Compressing file "+ i + "..")
                        logfile.write(command + "..\n\n")
                        os.system(command)
                        incrementCompressedFileCount()
                        incrementCompressedCSSFileCount()
                        logErrorWarning(cssMinPath + "/log/" + i[0:-4] + ".log.txt")

        logfile.close()

def contains(list, element):
        flag = False
        for x in list:
                if x == element:
                        flag = True
        return flag


def minifyAll():
        minifyJs()
        minifyCss()

def logoutput(text):
        if enable_log:
                print (text)

def printsummary():
        global total_files_compressed
        global total_js_files_compressed
        global total_css_files_compressed
        print ("----------------------Summary--------------------")
        print '%6s %10s' % ("Total", str(total_files_compressed))
        print '%6s %10s' % ("JS", str(total_js_files_compressed))
        print '%6s %10s' % ("CSS", str(total_css_files_compressed))
        print ("-------------------------------------------------")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group1.add_argument("--all",help="Minify all files",action="store_true")
group1.add_argument("--js",help="Minify all js files",action="store_true")
group1.add_argument("--css",help="Minify all css files",action="store_true")
group1.add_argument("--clear",help="Clear existing files in min",action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.all:
        minifyAll()
elif args.js:
        minifyJs()
elif args.css:
        minifyCss()
elif args.clear:
        print "Clear files"


if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        minifyAll()

end_time = time.time()
printsummary()

if total_warnings:
        print "Total warnings " + "\033[1;38m"+ str(total_warnings)+"\033[1;m"
else:
        print "Total warnings " + str(total_warnings)

if total_warnings:
        print "Total errors " + "\033[1;31m"+ str(total_errors)+"\033[1;m"
else:
        print "Total errors " + str(total_errors)

print "Time taken for execution(seconds)"
print abs(start_time - end_time)
```

The repo link is [this](https://github.com/hkasera/minify).

The code stores logs and compresses js and css files. Please suggest any possible optimization or improvement.

Comment: I removed the javascript tag, that tag is meant for the language of the code.

Comment: Same for the css tag.

Comment: I disagree with both of you.  this has everything to do with CSS and JS. you have to know the syntax to minify the language.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if not os.path.exists(jsMinPath + "/log"):
            os.makedirs(jsMinPath + "/log")
    else:
            shutil.rmtree(jsMinPath + "/log")
            os.makedirs(jsMinPath + "/log")
```

could be

```
    if os.path.exists(jsMinPath + "/log"):
            shutil.rmtree(jsMinPath + "/log")
    os.makedirs(jsMinPath + "/log")
```

Also

```
def contains(list, element):
        flag = False
        for x in list:
                if x == element:
                        flag = True
        return flag
```

could be

```
def contains(list, element):
        return element in list
```

and for that reason is probably not required (it doesn't seem to be used anyway).

No time to go further at the moment. I might edit my answer later on.